# SQL - Join Parent-Child tables. How can I build this query?

Tags: jquery, sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I have the following tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIzTc.png
I need to build a query to select data from all tables.

I know that to get data between A, B, C and D; I should make a left join, but the trouble is when I try to join E and F.

- Is it possible to get all data in a single query? how?
- I think that one solution is to make a left join between A and immediates child tables (B, C, D) and then make inner join in B-E, C-E and D-F for every row, but is it a good solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: **What** data do you need to select? Do you think you asked a complete, self-contained question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no data reference is given i have taken a level based input for tables

```
WITH tab_a AS
 (SELECT     'Tab_A_' || LEVEL a_id_a, 'Tab_A_VAL_' || LEVEL a_col_1,
             'Tab_A_VAL_' || (LEVEL + 10) a_col_2
        FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9),
 tab_b AS
 (SELECT     'Tab_A_' || LEVEL b_id_a, 'Tab_B_' || LEVEL b_id_b,
             'Tab_B_VAL_' || LEVEL b_col_1,
             'Tab_B_VAL_' || (LEVEL + 20) b_col_2
        FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL BETWEEN 1 AND 5),
 tab_c AS
 (SELECT     'Tab_A_' || LEVEL c_id_a, 'Tab_C_' || LEVEL c_id_c,
             'Tab_C_VAL_' || LEVEL c_col_1,
             'Tab_C_VAL_' || (LEVEL + 30) c_col_2
        FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL BETWEEN 1 AND 5),
 tab_d AS
 (SELECT     'Tab_A_' || LEVEL d_id_a, 'Tab_D_' || LEVEL d_id_d,
             'Tab_D_VAL_' || LEVEL d_col_1,
             'Tab_D_VAL_' || (LEVEL + 40) d_col_2
        FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL BETWEEN 1 AND 5),
 tab_e AS
 (SELECT     'Tab_B_' || LEVEL e_id_b, 'Tab_C_' || LEVEL e_id_c,
             'Tab_E_' || LEVEL e_id_e, 'Tab_E_VAL_' || LEVEL e_col_1,
             'Tab_E_VAL_' || (LEVEL + 50) e_col_2
        FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL BETWEEN 1 AND 3),
 tab_f AS
 (SELECT     'Tab_D_' || LEVEL f_id_d, 'Tab_F_' || LEVEL f_id_f,
             'Tab_F_VAL_' || LEVEL f_col_1,
             'Tab_F_VAL_' || (LEVEL + 60) f_col_2
        FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL BETWEEN 1 AND 4) SELECT   *
FROM tab_a a LEFT OUTER JOIN tab_b b ON (a.a_id_a = b.b_id_a)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tab_c c ON (a.a_id_a = c.c_id_a)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tab_d d ON (a.a_id_a = d.d_id_a)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tab_e e
     ON (b.b_id_b = e.e_id_b AND c.c_id_c = e.e_id_c)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tab_f f ON (d.d_id_d = f.f_id_d)ORDER BY 1
```

Note the joins. B&C are joined with E when B&C are not null. Same as join for D to F.
Hope this helps.